Why Matomo doesn't return yesterday's data
I'm using self-hosted Matomo but I'm having an issue. I'm using the Live.getLastVisitsDetails API but I only get data up to the last day of last month's. I don't get yesterday's data neither any data from the current month.
I've used their endpoint to archive the results and still nothing.
Is there more to that than I know?
Thanks
